# Javascript errors effect on browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I provide some additional services to websites that add my script to their site. Technically my script does not interact with actual functionality of the site, the most is does is read some information and the main part of the code only runs only after the event (think something like Google Analytics).

Recently a bug caused an "X is undefined" error to occur in some circumstances and the client insists that this error is crashing their site. They sent me a screenshot that shows a blank page and a console screenshot that shows the error but they removed my code so I was not able to see it in real time.

My question is if there is any possibility that these types of errors can affect the website. For example assume this code runs on the website:

```
var tmp = Sizzle('h1');
tmp[0].innerHTML = "test";
```

Assume that for some reason Sizzle is not defined when the code runs or that there weren't any H1 elements on the page so `tmp` is empty. Could the resulting error under any circumstances affect the outside environment. e.g the page the code runs on? Obviously if I had overwritten the body element then yes it will affect the website but my question is only about "x is undefined" or syntax errors.

Comment: Generally, a blank page means some rendering issue which is more often than not, triggered by something with JavaScript. The general rule is that as long as you don't interact with something rendered, it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, there are circumstances that error of the type "X is undefined" affects the whole website.

If the code which produces "X is undefined" error is:

- *inside a function* or *inside an object method* - it will stop this current function from execution but likely will **proceed** with the script below it.
- written as *a row by row Javascript statements* it will **stop** on this current point and **won't proceed** with else script.

Probably your client has more Javascript statements (loading content of the page) below the crashing pont, these statements are not executed and the content is not loaded.

You can simply add to your script:

```
    if (typeof variable !== 'undefined')
    {
        // else part of the code
    }
```

Comment: My script is added in it's own <script> tag and the client's site functionality doesn't depend on my script. So if I have an error in my script will it somehow affect other scripts that run in parallel or that are added in other <script> tags?

Comment: Your own <script> tag is not a boundary at all. `<script>...<script>` is a boundary for HTML, making a place for some Javascript inside it. A Javascript function or an object can make boundaries. Moreover in many sites Javascript is combined into one big file.
So **yes**, the error in any Javascrip statement affects other scripts added into other <script> tags or even other files.

Answer (score 4):

An Error will break the execution of the current function-stack.

For example if you have a onclick event, that calls a function and you have an error at the beginning it will not execute anything after that code. But that doesn't mean that any JavaScript on your Website won't work anymore. Everything will still be fine and run. Of cause if there was something important that was not executed after an Error it would change the logic of your runtime.

You can also avoid Error to go down the function-stack with a try-catch block:

```js
function a() {
  var x = new DoesNotExist()
  alert("test a") // this will not alert() as there is an error before
}

function b() {
  try {
    var x = new DoesNotExist()
  } catch (e) {}
  alert("test b") // this will alert because the error is catched
}

alert("code is running")
a() 
b() // this will not execute as a() broke this script
// however pressing the button b will still alert in b() as it's in a new stack
alert("code finished")
```

```html
<input onclick="a()" value="a" type="button" />
<input onclick="b()" value="b" type="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As JavaScript is a scripting language which alters the DOM and provides user interaction I'd say: in general as long as you do not interfere with the site's content it will not affect the page being loaded. There are two possibilities I could imagine stopping the page from showing up:

- your javascript lead to a infinite loop and therefore blocks the content being loaded (but they should have gotten an error like the page not reacting)
- the depend the building of their page on stuff they intended to do using your code so it will not load because it doesn't have your code